# How can I copy files that are not bigger than 200MB using the terminal?

Tags: command-line

The question says it all. I want to copy files in the terminal, but there are a few big files I don't want to copy (because they are backups). Is there a command to do that?

Something like `cp --max-size=200MB`?

I know `rsync` has such an option. Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the `find` command to build a list of files under 200MB and copy them to a `dir`.

```
find . -size -200M -exec cp -r {} dir/ \;
```

Comment: Using `-200` is a must, if you leave out the `-`, you won't get any results. the `-` indicates 'smaller than'

Comment: to exclude subdirectories, use `-maxdepth 1` also as a param for the find command.

Comment: Does this work for you? For me it's copying all files, regardless of the size. I suspect it's the -r ? find selects some directories, and then if they contain large files, they will be copied due to the -r (recursive) flag on cp, even if those files were excluded by the find filter.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I do it with `rsync`:

```
rsync --max-size=200MB --progress --verbose --recursive --links --perms  --ignore-existing --executability --owner --group --times SOURCE TARGET
```

I would still like to accept an `cp` solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
find . -size -200M -exec cp -r {} dir/ \;
```

didn´t work for me, because it copies all files when it finds a folder, because of the "r" flag on cp. I had to do the following:

1. Get the list of the files when their size is -200MB

   ```
    find /yourdirectory -type f -size -200M > list.txt
   ```
2. Then, copy the files from the list.txt.

   ```
    cp --parents  $(cat list.txt) /newFolder
   ```

   The "cp" and the "--parents" flag will copy the files and create the necessary folder tree.
3. After that, you have to move the folder to the right place, but it´s simple.

Hope it helps.